# Ocelot - gRPC service?

Tags: .net-core, grpc, ocelot

How I can use Ocelot Gateway for gRPC service in .Net Core 3.1?

Ocelot not support gRPC or is there any way to integrate it?
Hope to help, thank you!

Comment: you can check [this specific issue](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/643) on the official repository

Answer (score 0):

Currently Ocelot does not provide this functionality out of the box, but you can find some workarounds here:

1. https://github.com/BuiltCloud/Ocelot.GrpcHttpGateway
2. https://github.com/thangchung/GrpcJsonTranscoder

Personally, I haven't used any of them but it's worth a try.

Comment: This will be useful only in case of gRPC Request-Reply pattern. Load balancing gRPC streaming pattern is still a challenge